# Rango de fechas SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen dia quisiera saber si hay una forma en sql de un rango de fechas me de si el mes es completo
ejemplo si pongo el rango 20200101 AND 20200229 me ponga el numero del mes que este caso seria 1,2
enero, febrero, pero si selecciono 20200101 AND 20200215 como el rango final no es mes completo
tendria que ponerme solo el mes 1 tengo la siguiente query pero no hace como deseo.

```
SELECT FECHAS.ANIO, CONVERT(INT, FECHAS.MES), FECHAS.DESCR, FORMAT(FECHAS.FECHA,'d','eu') AS FECHA  
FROM (
    SELECT *, CONVERT(DATETIME,CONCAT(ANIOS.ANIO,MESES.MES,'01')) AS FECHA 
    FROM(
                 SELECT '2020' AS ANIO 


    ) AS ANIOS
    CROSS JOIN (    
        SELECT '01' AS MES, 'Ene' AS DESCR
        UNION 
        SELECT '02' AS MES, 'Feb' AS DESCR
        UNION 
        SELECT '03' AS MES, 'Mar' AS DESCR
        UNION 
        SELECT '04' AS MES, 'Abr' AS DESCR
        UNION 
        SELECT '05' AS MES, 'May' AS DESCR
        UNION 
        SELECT '06' AS MES, 'Jun' AS DESCR
        UNION 
        SELECT '07' AS MES, 'Jul' AS DESCR
        UNION 
        SELECT '08' AS MES, 'Ago' AS DESCR
        UNION 
        SELECT '09' AS MES, 'Sep' AS DESCR
        UNION 
        SELECT '10' AS MES, 'Oct' AS DESCR
        UNION 
        SELECT '11' AS MES, 'Nov' AS DESCR
        UNION 
        SELECT '12' AS MES, 'Dic' AS DESCR  
    ) MESES 
) AS FECHAS
WHERE FECHA BETWEEN '20200101' AND '20200229'
ORDER BY FECHA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes saber los meses que los separan utilizando dateDiff

```
DECLARE @FECHADESDE DATE = '20200101';
DECLARE @FECHAHASTA DATE = '20200229'; -- MAX PERIODO VÁLIDO '99991231';

WITH 
L AS (
    SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,@FECHADESDE,@FECHAHASTA) 
        + CASE WHEN EOMONTH(@FECHAHASTA) = CAST(@FECHAHASTA AS DATE) 
               THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
          END AS DifMeses),
L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (VALUES(1),(1)) AS D(c)),
L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
L6   AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
        FROM L5),
L7   AS (select DATEADD(MONTH,L6.rownum-1,@FECHADESDE) AS Fecha , L6.rownum
 FROM L6  WHERE 
        L6.rownum <= (SELECT L.DifMeses FROM L)
    )
SELECT    YEAR(l7.fecha) AS ANIO
        , L7.rownum as MES
        , SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MM, L7.FECHA),1,3) AS DESCR
        , FORMAT(l7.FECHA,'d','eu') AS FECHA
FROM L7;
```

Si no dispones de la función EOMOTH, puedes cambiarlo por el primer día del mes siguiente menos uno.

Si bien aún no tengo claro el objetivo, salvo que sea para aplicar una función y aplicarle un cross apply o un procedure con unos parámetros. De cualquier modo esta puede ser una solución.

[Funciones de fecha útiles](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/12/15/funciones-de-fecha-para-datetime-utiles/)

Comment: Está pidiendo una lista de meses, no la cantidad de meses completos que hay entre dos fechas.

Comment: Hola Luis Cazares: De la entrada de información ya que trabaja sólo con literales, no veo aún claro el objetivo. Evidentemente Javier Solis por el código que ha planteado, ya tiene conocimientos para hacer muchas cosas, de ahí que mi respuesta sólo le dió la parte que consideraba que le faltaba. O al menos algo que le ayudase a poder resolverlo.

Comment: ambas querys de hecho me sirvieron muy bien muchas gracias, ya pude implmentar la como query, muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Aquí hay una opción para hacerlo. Reduzco un poco el código para generar las fechas y que sirve para generar hasta 83 meses de puro intervalo.

```
--SET LANGUAGE spanish

DECLARE @FechaInicial date = '20200101',
        @FechaFinal   date = '20200229';

SELECT *,
       YEAR(FECHAS.FECHA) AS ANIO, 
       MONTH( FECHAS.FECHA) AS MES, 
       DATENAME( MM, FECHAS.FECHA) AS DESCR, 
       REPLACE( CONVERT( varchar(10), FECHAS.FECHA,120), '-', '/') AS FECHA  , 1000/12
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(MM, @FechaInicial, @FechaFinal) + 1)
            DATEADD(MM, x.n + (y.n*10) + (z.n*100), DATENAME(YYYY, @FechaInicial)) AS FECHA 
    FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9))x(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9))y(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9))z(n)
    ORDER BY FECHA
) AS FECHAS
WHERE FECHA >= CASE WHEN DAY(@FechaInicial) = 1 THEN @FechaInicial ELSE DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, '19000101',@FechaInicial) + 1, '19000101') END
AND   FECHA <= CASE WHEN @FechaFinal = EOMONTH(@FechaFinal) THEN @FechaFinal ELSE DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, '19000101', @FechaFinal), '18991231') END
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: me sirvio mucho el codigo al final le modifique un poquito pero me sirvio mucho gracias